# Why my dgram socket client won't read any message?

Tags: c

Whenever I run my server and client, I successfully receive a message on my server terminal, but whenever I send back the message to client, it hangs on `read` and doesn't print anything. I've removed the error checking for code readability. It doesn't throw any errors. I am not sure why is this happening. Am I doing something wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <netinet/udp.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
```

```c
int main()
{
    unlink("tmp/unix1");
    int server = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

    // bind
    struct sockaddr_un address, client;
    address.sun_family = AF_UNIX; 
    strcpy(address.sun_path, "/tmp/unix12");

    char buff[1024] = "Message to server";
    char rcvMsg[1024];

    int len = sizeof(client);

    int bindc = bind(server, (struct sockaddr *)&address, sizeof(address));
    if(bindc==-1) {
        perror("bind");
        return -1;
    }

    while(1) {
    if(recvfrom(server, rcvMsg, 1024, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &client,
            &len) == -1){
         perror("recvfrom");
         return -1;
      }
        printf("from client: %s\n", rcvMsg);
        sendto(server, buff, 1024, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&client, sizeof(client));

    }

    close(server);

    return 0;
}
```

Client:

```c
int main()
{
    int server = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

    // bind
    struct sockaddr_un address, client;
    address.sun_family = AF_UNIX; 
    strcpy(address.sun_path, "/tmp/unix12");

    char buff[1024] = "Message to server";
    char rcvMsg[1024];

    int len = sizeof(address);

    sendto(server, buff, 1024, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&address, sizeof(address));
    if(recvfrom(server, rcvMsg, 1024, 0, NULL, NULL) == -1) {
        perror("rcv");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("%s\n\n", rcvMsg);
    close(server);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's because the server sends to itself, instead of the client. Can we call this a typo?

Comment: also, this isn't UDP

Comment: also the client needs to `connect()` to an `AF_UNIX` socket.

Comment: @user253751 how do I send it to the client?

Comment: sendto the client's address instead of the server's address? The next question should then be: what's the client's address? and the answer is: if you use recvfrom, it will tell you.

Comment: I dont understand this - how will recvfrom tell me the client address? it only returns buffer size. I tried using recvfrom in my code but still same issue. I've updated my code

Comment: @user253751 is it not possible to return message to client with unix dgram or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Halaviw it is possible but you have to send the return message to the client's address. recvfrom receives a message and tells you which address the message came from. so you can send the return message back to that address.

Comment: @user253751 but I am using recvfrom on server side and then sending back to client address. Please see my updated code. I have spent on this already 2 days and I have no clue whats wrong. I am successfully receiving the message on server, but when I am receiving it on client side it's not printing the message.

Comment: If you check how the length is used in each call, when you call recvfrom it should be the maximum space available to hold the address; after recvfrom returns it's the actual address size; sendto needs to know the actual address size. unix socket addresses are not all the same size since the path can have a different size.